# widget="selection" with domain fields issue

Tags: python, xml, odoo

here is my view xml part

```
<field name="bpl_estate_id" placeholder="Estate" widget="selection" />
```

here is my model python part

```
'bpl_company_id':fields.many2one('res.company', 'Company', help='Company'),
'bpl_estate_id':fields.many2one('bpl.estate.n.registration', 'Estate', 
domain="[('company_id','=',bpl_company_id)]"),
```

my issue is when i used estate field,with widget option, then no domain filtered ?
(show all records)

please advice me to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic domains are not supported on selection widgets, simple as that

https://lists.launchpad.net/openerp-india/msg03333.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an `onchange` to set the domain dynamically. [Look at this](http://help.openerp.com/question/11253/how-to-create-dynamic-domain-on-many2one-fields-with-onchange-function/).

Comment: means there was a issue with widget option and domain option.?
then please advice me to write function

Comment: I can't code for you :) the link I just gave you has a complete example on how to achieve this. Also, you can grep into addons folder to get more example (usually onchange methods names containg 'onchange' word). Then, pls, consider marking the answer as correct.

Comment: thanks simahawk.
i will refer the same type functions from another addons and try
:-)