# OpenERP 7: relational fields in client-side domain filters

Tags: python, xml, odoo

here shows my error

```
2013-04-23 05:36:03,877 17001 ERROR demo openerp.sql_db: bad query: SELECT "res_company".id FROM "res_company" WHERE "res_company".id = 'deduction_id.bpl_company_id.id' ORDER BY "res_company"."name"  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bellvantage/Documents/openerp-7.0/openerp-7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "deduction_id.bpl_company_id.id"
LINE 1: ...y".id FROM "res_company" WHERE "res_company".id = 'deduction...
                                                             ^

2013-04-23 05:36:03,878 17001 ERROR demo openerp.osv.osv: Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

here shows my code which i trying to add domain filter

```
class estate_bank_deductions(osv.osv):
    _name = 'bpl.estate.bank.deductions'
    _description = 'Estate Bank Deductions'
    _columns = {
                'deduction_id':fields.many2one('bpl.deduction.estate.data', 'Bank Deductions', ondelete='cascade'),
                'name': fields.many2one('bpl.deduction.registration', 'Deduction', domain="[('type','=','bank'),('bpl_company_id.id','=','deduction_id.bpl_company_id.id')]"),
                'bank_id': fields.many2one('bpl.bank.registration', 'Bank Name'),
                'branch_id': fields.many2one('bpl.branch.registration', 'Branch'),
        }
```

here is part of my parent class of estate bank deduction class

```
_name = 'bpl.deduction.estate.data'
_description = 'BPL Deduction Estate Data'
_columns = {
            'bpl_company_id':fields.many2one('res.company', 'Company', help='Company'),
```

please help me to sort out this.?
is there anything missing in my domain filtering mechanism or is that way is incorrect.?

---

Dear odony,

one more thing to clarify, 
now need to define my field as `fields.function` ?

but the issue is after adding the domain filter also other irrelevant records also loaded to my drop down (after i added the widget="selection" attribute).
then how to restrict them. [i already posted that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134784/widget-selection-with-domain-fields-issue)

hope you will advice me on this...again thanks u soo much

Comment: There is no reason to define your field as a `fields.function`, the `on_change` call creates the dynamic behavior with plain regular fields.

Comment: Also you cannot use `widget="selection"` with client-side domains because this converts the many2one field to a virtual `fields.selection`, and the available values are computed statically server-side (they cannot be dynamic). So you should use the default many2one widget for this case.

Comment: I updated the answer to mention the widget="selection" case, and some possible workarounds... it depends on why you wanted to use this kind of widget...

Comment: Wow......marvellous Odony..
its worked & ur explaination very very helpful to me
thanks a lot...  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't work either way. Model fields support only two kind of domain filters:

- **Server-side (list) domains**, specified as a list of tuples: can only be static and are meant to be used for [**`one2many`**](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/03_module_dev_02/#relational-types) and [**`many2many`**](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/03_module_dev_02/#relational-types) fields mostly. These filters will be applied on the server-side when reading the list of values for the field, and will never be used on the client-side. The domain can only contain constants on the right side of each domain element. An example of a valid server-side domain is:

  ```
  # filter deductions based on an imaginary "confirmed" boolean field
  deduction_ids = fields.one2many('bpl.estate.bank.deductions', 'bank_id',
                                  string="Confirmed Deductions",
                                  domain=[('confirmed', '=', True)])
  ```
- **Client-side (string) domains**, specified as the *string representation* of a server-side domain: can be static or dynamic, and are meant to be used for [**`many2one`**](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/03_module_dev_02/#relational-types) fields mostly, and never evaluated on the server-side. They are simply copied in any view where the field is used, and interpreted on the client-side to filter the list of available choices for that field. The right hand side of each domain element can be made dynamic by referring to the name of any other field included in the view, and will be replaced by the field value when the domain is evaluated. The field value will be returned in the same format that it would be passed to [`write()`](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/api_models/#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.write) when saving the changes. An example of a valid client-side domain is:

  ```
  # only allow choosing a branch that belongs to the right bank registration
  # (here `branch_id` refers to the current value of the `branch_id` field
  # in the form view
  'branch_id': fields.many2one('bpl.branch.registration', 'Branch',
                               domain="[('branch_id','=',branch_id)]")
  ```

  **UPDATE:** watch out, you cannot use `widget="selection"` in combination with client-side domains because this option converts your `many2one` field into a fake `fields.selection` whose options are statically evaluated server-side. In this case your client-side domain will be ignored and the list of available values will never change. Now if you simply want to avoid users creating new values you can restrict access rights to prevent that, and if you want to avoid showing an icon to view/edit the target object you can add `options='{"no_open": True}'` to the field in the form view.

### **Problem**

In your case it seems you want to use a client-side domain to filter based on the current value of the `deduction_id` field. But your domain expression `('bpl_company_id.id','=','deduction_id.bpl_company_id.id')` is incorrect:

- The left hand side must refer to a field or a field path, and the `.id` suffix is useless here, `bpl_company_id` is sufficient to filter on that `many2one` field.
- The right hand side can be dynamic or static, depending if you make it a constant or a variable. If you quote the value as `'deduction_id.bpl_company_id.id'` then you're comparing the `m2o` ID (or the `m2o` name if your remove the `.id` suffix) to the literal string value `"deduction_id.bpl_company_id.id"`, certainly not what you want.
  If you remove the quoting as suggested by user2310008 you will make it dynamic indeed, but the value of the `deduction_id` will be the ID of the selected "deduction"! You cannot treat it as a `browse_record` (ActiveRecord-like object) like on the server-side, so when you do `"deduction_id.bpl_company_id.id"` you'll get an error because an integer has no `bpl_company_id` attribute.

### **Solution**

The usual way to implement this kind of filtering is to add an [`on_change`](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/06_misc_on_change_tips/#on-change-methods) method on the `deduction_id` field, and use it to dynamically alter the domain of the `name` column, via the `domain` key that `onchange` methods can return. Something like this:

```xml
    <!-- in the XML view -->
    <field name="deduction_id" on_change="onchange_deduction_id(deduction_id)"/>
    <field name="name"/>
```

```python
    # in the python model
    def onchange_deduction_id(self, cr, uid, ids, deduction_id, context=None):
        if deduction_id:
            deduction = self.pool['bpl.deduction.estate.data'].browse(cr, uid,
                                                                      deduction_id,
                                                                      context)
            return {'domain': {'name': [('bpl_company_id', '=',
                                         deduction.bpl_company_id.id)]}
        return {} # or perhaps a default domain?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
('bpl_company_id','=',deduction_id.bpl_company_id.id)
```

Without quotes the second part, and the field can not be done recursively.

Comment: then issue comes 'Error: AttributeError: object has no attribute 'bpl_company_id''

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't read more carefully your code I will edit my answer you have an error on reference the pointer in you many2one.

Comment: But one thing: What exactly didn't work for you in Oliver Dony's solution?